# Instagram API New Compatibility

Tags: instagram

I've used the Instagram API a number of times, the /tags/{foo}/media/recent and /users/self/media/recent/ endpoints.

It seems the new changes won't affect the API calls, however I'm uncertain over the apps. I've been making apps for each client inside their account so they're fetching their own info.

To ensure it continues working in future, will they work in sandbox mode? (as it's fetching their own info which from what I read doesn't need authorization). Or will I need to login to each clients account, then press some sort of 'submit for review' button. Is it that simple or will there be additional work required?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the information they've released so far to be frustratingly vague. From what I can tell there are a bunch of endpoints going away in favor of the new endpoints listed on the current developer page.

According to their change log they've deprecated the endpoints you're looking at:

Private content only available to content owner
Deprecation of /users/self/feed
Deprecation of /media/popular
Deprecation of /geographies/media/recent
Deprecation of Realtime subscriptions for tags, locations and geographies
API responses containing media objects no longer return the data field in comments and likes nodes

https://instagram.com/developer/changelog/

Comment: I'm using /users/self/media/recent (their pictures vs their feed) and /tags/. From what I can tell instagram are trying to kill anything that can replicate instagram.com. The part which I think will be PITA, is trying to remember which clients have an instagram feed, then getting their logins, doing the app approval. I may have to do 1 site to find out, was hoping someone had some info as yes, bit vague!. It mentioned sandbox mode, 'developers can only fetch their own info' - which given clients are fetching their own images, may mean I don't need to submit it for approval.

Comment: I think you'll be ok, the way I read it was "if you want to display a user's Instagram feed they need to authorize you to do so". It's more about data control than data restriction.